# json_decode can't deserialize properly

Tags: php, json, api, rest, curl

I've made a RestAPI that working pretty well, at the top of my script (the core file), I have declared this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
```

Now the problem is that when I pass a json from the client to my API. This problem is related on the `POST` and `PUT` method, usually. This happean only if I pass this type of json with curl:

```
curl -i -d '{"test": "èè"}'
```

How you can see I've some accented letters. So when I call this function:

```
$params = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

the `$params` variable return `NULL`. Instead if my json looks like this:

```
curl -i -d '{"test": "This is a test"}'
```

all working good, and the `$params` variable have this valorization:

```
array(1) {
  ["test"]=>
  string(14) "This is a test"
}
```

I guess that the special character cause problem on this function.. Someone have a solution for this?

Comment: Your terminal is utf-8 safe? I got correct result even with `{"test": "èè"}`

Comment: @fusion3k I tested this on `MINGW64` git console, and also on the Chrome extension (Adavanced RestFul API). Both they reported the same result.

Comment: go in chatroom please

Comment: @fusion3k I'm in chat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regex to determine if the input line contains accented characters.

```
<?php

  preg_match("/[À-ÿ].*/", $input_line, $output_array);

  if(sizeof($output_array) > 0){
    echo "$input_line has accented characters";
  }

?>
```

You can also take a look at [URL encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), because I think the issue is there.

Comment: regex? Really? is this a lack of `json_decode`? There is no other way to fix this?

Comment: There is also a possible way to [encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) before submission

Comment: uhm, `urlencode()` seems interesting. Should I use it each time I need to decode a json, or is possible do this automatically in some part of the API?

Comment: You should encode the value before submission, `è` to `&#232;` and use decode to change `&#232;` back to `è`. However decoding may not be necessary but it would make the *above* regex fail to do its job if you don't.

Comment: Sorry but I really want avoid the use of regex.